# geoIP find country from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, web-services, geoip

From an ASP.NET page I'm able to retrieve the client's IP address (at least the apparent one).

I would like to know if there is a free service that I can access from code-behind, that will return the country (no need for city) when queried with the IP.

I can't make do with web http based services where you have to enter the IP manually, I have thousands of visits per day!

Any clue welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [Check It Out](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php)!

Good luck!

EDITED: Since you did not specify a language I went ahead and created my own key for testing purposes and made this little sample. This gets the Country of any given IP address. Good luck.

```
Try
        Dim webClient As WebClient = New WebClient

        'I am at work so i need a proxy authentication
        'webClient.Proxy.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")

        Dim stream As Stream = webClient.OpenRead("http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-country/?key=<key here>&ip=" & Context.Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR"))
        Dim sReader As New StreamReader(stream)
        Dim content As String = sReader.ReadToEnd()
        Response.Write(content.Split(";")(4))

    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write("Error occured")
    End Try
```

Comment: for the simpkicity and using VB! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I use [WIPmania](http://www.wipmania.com/), very, very easy:

```
http://api.wipmania.com/123.45.67.89
```

returns two-letter country code ("KR" Republic of Korea)

```
KR
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this that might be up your alley.

[IP2Location](http://www.ip2locationapi.com/geoip-location-api/index.php)