# How to get the location where my website is accessed using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

How to get the location where my Web Site is been accessed using C# code in ASP.NET. The basic requirement is to know the requested location and redirect the request to the nearest data center. So the response would be faster for further requests.

Many Thanks,
Thiru.

Comment: Redirect you to :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657855/geoip-find-country-from-asp-net

Comment: Generally this sort of routing generally happens *below* the application level. In fact, the (ASP.NET) application has effectively no way of routing itself, excepting redirecting to an alternate host/IP address.